# Grunt not concatenating using grunt-contrib-concat

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I've got the following in my Gruntfile.js:

```
concat: {
  options: {
    // define a string to put between each file in the concatenated output
    separator: ';'
  },
  dist: {
    // the files to concatenate
    src: [
        'scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js', 
        'scripts/SmoothScroll.js',
        'scripts/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js', 
        'scripts/jquery.bxslider.js',
        'scripts/jquery.hoverdir.js', 
        'scripts/jquery.mixitup.js',
        'scripts/jquery.fitvids.js', 
        'scripts/respond.min.js',
        'scripts/theme.script.js', 
        'scripts/theme.settings.js'
    ],
    // the location of the resulting JS file
    dest: 'scripts.js'
  }
}
```

But when I run `grunt concat` nothing happens.  The task is loaded and registered with:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.registerTask('concat', ['concat']);
```

I don't get any errors, but the file `scripts.js` is not created. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's the point of `grunt.registerTask('concat', ['concat']);` ? Using the same name is a recipe for disaster. Just remove that line and try again `grunt concat`.

Comment: Ah, that's what the problem was. I thought that you had to register all tasks but I guess that is just for doing multiple tasks?

Comment: Well, you need to register a task if you are actually creating a new one. Here, you are barely *using* the concat task (defined by the plugin). Anyhow, did that solve your problem?

Comment: Yes it did. Thanks very much. If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I posted it as an answer. Happy it helped! Best.

Answer (score 0):

What's the point of `grunt.registerTask('concat', ['concat']);` ?

Using the same name is a recipe for disaster. Just remove that line and try again `grunt concat`.

Answer (score 0):

add src and dest inside files:

```
concat: {
  options: {
    // define a string to put between each file in the concatenated output
    separator: ';'
  },
  dist: {
    files:[{
    // the files to concatenate
    src: [
        'scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js', 
        'scripts/SmoothScroll.js',
        'scripts/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js', 
        'scripts/jquery.bxslider.js',
        'scripts/jquery.hoverdir.js', 
        'scripts/jquery.mixitup.js',
        'scripts/jquery.fitvids.js', 
        'scripts/respond.min.js',
        'scripts/theme.script.js', 
        'scripts/theme.settings.js'
    ],
    // the location of the resulting JS file
    dest: 'scripts.js'
    }]
  }
}
```